# MySQL how to calculate a correlation of a string fields?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to correlate b/w the two different data's like location with product in the table. so  i need to correlate the two column location and Product in from Retail database.
I have one method with the numerical correlation,but i dont know how to do with string correlation. Please help in this .. and thanks for supporting

Regards,
Shashikant

Comment: You need to give additional information. Ideally this would be table structure sample data and expected output. Showing us your attempts would also be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shashikant.

And what if you take each character in the string as a number.

Currently the most commonly used computer systems, used text encodings UTF8, ANSI, ASCII ..., in which the alphabet have ​"numeric" values as actually stored and processed...

For example the string "correlate" could be represented as
sequence numbers of 8 or 16 bits ie:

Seeing in hexadecimal notation (C, O, R, R, E, L, A, T, E) becomes:
43, 4F, 52, 52, 45, 4C, 41, 54, 45

in decimal
67, 79, 82, 82, 69, 76, 65, 84, 69

Account have each position, instead of being a number of from 0 to 9,
is 0 to 256 (8 bits).

There are some details to consider, but for practical purposes could help.

Regards, Carlos Ball